# How does this line of code (Solidity) work?

Tags: solidity

```
        User storage user = users[msg.sender];
```

I have a "User" struct:

```
    struct User {
    Deposit[] deposits;
    uint256 checkpoint;
    address referrer;
    uint256[3] levels;
    uint256 bonus;
    uint256 totalBonus;
}
```

And a "users" mapping:

```
    mapping (address => User) internal users;
```

The function the original line only asks for:

```
function intense(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {
```

So I understand what a mapping is and what the Struct is (I'm a beginner) I'm just very confused about the first line:
If I understand well, "users[msg.sender]" refers to the item in the "users" mapping with the key value "msg.sender". However, I don't remember creating this. If I am creating this, I don't understand how I created it when the "users" mapping only includes the "User" struct and I haven't given all the information the user struct needs. Plus, I don't know what the new "user" is.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Edit:
Can't seem to add the function in "code" in comments, so here it is:

```
    function invest(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT);
    require(plan < 6, "Invalid plan");

    uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(PROJECT_FEE).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
    commissionWallet.transfer(fee);
    emit FeePayed(msg.sender, fee);

    User storage user = users[msg.sender];

    if (user.referrer == address(0)) {
        if (users[referrer].deposits.length > 0 && referrer != msg.sender) {
            user.referrer = referrer;
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the complete function?

Comment: Here's the function's beginning, I don't think the rest is necessary:  
```
function invest(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {
  require(msg.value >= INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT);
        require(plan < 6, "Invalid plan");

  uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(PROJECT_FEE).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
  commissionWallet.transfer(fee);
  emit FeePayed(msg.sender, fee);

  User storage user = users[msg.sender];
```
  if (user.referrer == address(0)) {
   if (users[referrer].deposits.length > 0 && referrer != msg.sender) {
    user.referrer = referrer;
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
User storage user = users[msg.sender];
```

This line check the mapping `users` and gets the `User` object corresponding to the address `msg.sender`. It then assigns this `User` object to a variable named `user`. It does not create a new object, it simply fetch an already existing `User` object and assign it to a variable.

As you mentioned, it implies that a `User` object was previously created and assigned to `msg.sender` address in the `users` mapping.

Comment: Well, the problem is, the code never creates a User object before. The Struct exists but no User has been pushed and no function to create one has been used. That's my problem here: I don't think there's anything in the users mapping at the [msg.sender] key value.

Edit:

Comment: Well then you have to create User objects and assign them in the users mapping!

Comment: No Undead8 I don't have to. The code works without needing to have anything already assigned to the users mapping so you'd be wrong here.

Comment: User objects must be created somewhere in your code or the struct would return null. If not, then we are in presence of a self-aware machine that may soon take-over the world.

Comment: I just want to clarify that yes the mapping may return something, but it will be null and will have no use at all. If you want it to return a User, you have to create that User beforehand.